# 2D Array Display

Tags: java, arrays

This question relates to my 2D array display, which currently looks something like this.

```
    A B C D
 1: 0 0 0 0
 2: 0 0 0 0 
 3: 0 0 0 0
```

I am trying to get location (0,0) to change to the number 1 as this will be the start of my count.

However it won't change and remains as a zero, here is my code.

```
int[][] chessBoard = new int[3][4];                                                                                 
int rowhead = 1;                                                                                                    
    TextIO.put("  ");                                                                                               
for (int col = 0; col < chessBoard[0].length; col++)                                                                
    TextIO.putf("%4s",((char) ('A' + col)));                                                                        
    TextIO.putln();                                                                                                 

for (int [] row:chessBoard){                                                                                        
    TextIO.put(rowhead++ + ":");                                                                                    
for (int griddisplay:row)                                                                                       
    TextIO.putf("%4d", griddisplay);                                                                                
    TextIO.putln();                                                                                                 
    chessBoard [0][0] = 1;
```

Now this keeps my coordinates (o, o) displaying a zero, however if I change this
    chessBoard [0][0] = 1;
to this 
    chessBoard [1][0] = 1;

Then the grid does change accordingly to

```
    A B C D
 1: 0 0 0 0
 2: 1 0 0 0 
 3: 0 0 0 0
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It seems you are printing before you are changing ?

Comment: What is TextIO? This code is incomplete, and the indentation indicates you may not understand the scope of a for loop.

Comment: Can you post more of your code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `chessBoard [0][0] = 1;` right below the `TextIO.put(rowhead++ + ":");`:

```
int[][] chessBoard = new int[3][4];
    int rowhead = 1;
    TextIO.put("  ");
    for (int col = 0; col < chessBoard[0].length; col++)
        TextIO.putf("%4s",((char) ('A' + col)));
    TextIO.putln();

    for (int [] row:chessBoard) {
        TextIO.put(rowhead++ + ":");
        chessBoard[2][3] = 1;
        for (int griddisplay : row){
            TextIO.putf("%4d", griddisplay);
        }
        TextIO.putln();
    }
```

and it will work propertly =).

Comment: I tested the code my self and it works, i don't understand why the downvote?

Comment: I done as you advised, you are correct in that it does work. I'm pretty new to this so unsure why you were marked down!

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, I just added a few methods and altered output

```
public class Chessboard
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] chessBoard = new int[3][4];                                                                                                                                                                                    

        print(chessBoard);

        chessBoard [0][0] = 1;
        print(chessBoard);

        chessBoard [1][0] = 1;
        print(chessBoard);

        clear(chessBoard);
        print(chessBoard);
    }

    public static void print(int[][] chessBoard)
    {
        int rowhead = 1; 
        System.out.print("\n  ");                                                                                               
        for (int col = 0; col < chessBoard[0].length; col++)
            System.out.printf("%4s",((char) ('A' + col)));                                                                      
        System.out.println();                                                                                                

        for (int[] row : chessBoard)
        {
            System.out.print(rowhead++ + ":");                                                                                    
            for (int griddisplay : row)                                                                                       
                System.out.printf("%4d", griddisplay);                                                                                
            System.out.println();                                                                                                 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void clear(int[][] chessBoard)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < chessBoard.length; row++)
            for(int col = 0; col < chessBoard[row].length; col++)
                chessBoard[row][col] = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You appear to have some formatting issues but from the gist of it:

You are constructing your chess board as an array [3][4] and by the looks of it that is 3 'rows' and 4 'columns' so your first index is your row number and second is column number.

You loop through the first 'row' to get the length (4) so are outputting 4 columns - correctly I am assuming.

You then move to printing the chessboard (though I don't see the matching curly brace }). First you loop across rows and then across columns.

For example:

```
for (int [] row:chessBoard) {                                                                                        
    TextIO.put(rowhead++ + ":");                                                                                    
    for (int griddisplay:row)                                                                                      
        TextIO.putf("%4d", griddisplay);                                                                                
    TextIO.putln();                                                                                              
    chessBoard [0][0] = 1;
}
```

If this is your code, the first loop starts processing the first row. It loops through the columns for the first row, THEN sets [0][0] to be 1... but you've already printed that so it won't be shown. If you replace it with [1][0], it actually sets that BEFORE printing the second row so correctly shows the value.

As a final tip, the curly braces specify the scope of the for loop. If you omit the braces, the loop only runs the statement immediately after it. A habit a lot of programmers get in to is to always explicitly use braces to avoid easy mistakes.